# Pass shopping cart details to Purchase Order Form

Tags: javascript, php, html, shopping-cart

I have a webpage for a product store split into three frames

- Left hand side pane/frame displays products
- Middle of the page is split into two - `top_half` - Displays the product details and quantity that the user wants to add when a product is selected.
- `bottom_half` of the frame displays the shopping cart when I select 'Submit' in the top half.

I want to submit the information from the shopping cart(`bottom_half`) to display the contents in the `top_half` as well as an order form for customer details.. this will close the session and display " to complete checkout please fill in the information above"

**Cart.php** (bottom_half)

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My Grocery Store</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS_prod.css">
</head>
<body>

<h2>My Shopping Cart</h2>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['empty_cart']))
{
    $_SESSION=array();
    session_desrtoy();
}
require_once 'class_product.php'; 

$product = unserialize($_SESSION['product']);
$quantity = $_POST['cart'];
$total_price = 0;

echo '<table class="Checkout">'; 
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Product Name</th>";
echo "<th>Product Id </th>";
echo "<th>In Stock</th>";
echo "<th>Price</th>";
echo "<th>Quantity Added</th>";
echo "<th>Cost</th>";
echo "</tr>";

if(!isSet($_SESSION['cart_items']))
{
  $_SESSION['cart_items'] = array();
}

array_push($_SESSION['cart_items'],$product->getProductName()."|".$product->getProductId()."|".$product->getStock()."|".$product->getUnitPrice()."|".$quantity."|".$sub_total);


for($i=0;$i<sizeof($_SESSION['cart_items']);$i++)
{


  $sub_total = $product->getUnitPrice() * $quantity;
  $total_price += $sub_total;
  echo "<tr>";
  //echo $_SESSION['cart_items'][$i]."<br><hr>";
  $params = explode("|",$_SESSION['cart_items'][$i]);


  for($j=0;$j<sizeof($params);$j++)

  {

    if($j == 0)
    {

      echo "<th>".$params[$j]."</th>";  
    }
    else
    {
      echo "<td>".$params[$j]."</td>";

    }        

  }
echo "</tr>";

}

echo"<tr>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td>Total Cost</td>";
echo "<td>$total_price</td>";
echo"</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>

<form name="endform" method="post">
<button type="submit" name="empty_cart" value="Delete" id="empty_cart">Delete</button>
<button type="submit" name="Checkout" value="Checkout" onlcick="purchase.php">Checkout</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: how can i display an order form in the top_half frame of my page along with the details of my shopping cart?

Comment: Sounds more like a requirement than a programming question. Can you elaborate this a little more and put aside things not really necessary to answer the question. E.g. simplify the example so it's more clear at which part you got stuck? Can you display but only not the details?